YA fantasy book about a brother and sister who are transported to a different world and turned into animals that represent them
I remember reading a book for free on my Kindle years and years ago and want to reread it but can't find it! I'm pretty sure the cover had like a panther on it, but not sure on the color because my Kindle was black and white.
It's about a brother and sister who are transported into a different world and are turned into animals that represent them. The sister turns into a bird, I believe a bird of prey of some sort, and the brother into a panther. The land and sky animals have different places to live; land animals underground in a cave and birds in a big tree. I am also pretty sure gemstones were involved? Not sure how, but they were specific to each character. I also remember a side character being an elephant. They have to fight off this mysterious mist invading their land that is full of monsters and the like.

In roughly which year did you read this?
